# Rearrange data to make pivot chart

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-excel, pivot-table

I am very new to Excel and have so far done a few basic pivot tables/charts.
I am trying to rearrange my source data to make a column chart where credits are shown in green and debits in red.[image]

Here's my original data I get from a database. Please note there's 3 sets of values A, B, C.

Set1 A, B, C refers to Credits
Set2 A, B, C refers to debits
Set3 A, B, C is the difference between Set1 A - Set2 A and so on..

I need to make a chart like the one below, Set1 of A,B,Cs are the green columns, Set2 of A, B, Cs are the red columns. Set3 A, B, Cs is hte difference displayed on top.

[image]
How do I do this? 
This is what I have done so far:

I hand edited and rearranged my original dataset to look like this: It was quite a bit of work to do this since I have a large amount of data.

[image]

Then I could make a chart out of this. But what I would like to know is if there's a better way to achieve this. Thanks much!

Update: Here's the data sample

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Year | Set1 A | Set1 B | Set1 C | Set2 A | Set2 B | Set2 C | Set3 A | Set3 B | Set3 C |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2010 |     58 |     33 |    111 |      0 |      0 |    300 |     58 |     33 |   -189 |
| 2011 |     56 |     33 |    112 |      0 |      0 |    300 |     56 |     33 |   -188 |
| 2012 |     56 |     33 |    112 |      0 |      0 |    300 |     56 |     33 |   -188 |
| 2013 |     56 |     33 |    112 |      0 |      0 |    300 |     56 |     33 |   -188 |
| 2014 |     56 |     30 |    102 |      0 |      0 |    300 |     56 |     30 |   -198 |
| 2015 |    134 |      0 |      0 |    190 |      0 |     60 |    -56 |      0 |    -60 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: i can't think of a way to transform your data using normal means. meaning, built in excel functionality. although i'm not 100% sure, your data can only be transformed using `VBA`.

Comment: @pnuts - I apologize. The chart and the table do not represent the same data. I missed the mismatch in data when taking screenshots. But my description is still true. Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts - thanks for the link. Updated post with the data sample.

Comment: @pnuts Ok thanks much for trying. I will look for other options. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is interested, I was able to rearrange data using the Excel add-in 'PowerQuery'. Powerquery is available for Excel 2010 Professional and beyond. It let me unpivot my table data and with a few clicks I got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I was able to rearrange data using the Excel add-in 'PowerQuery'. Powerquery is available for Excel 2010 Professional and beyond. It let me unpivot my table data and with a few clicks I got it to work. Thanks.